# Mysql multiple replace query leaving unwanted leading white space. How to remove it?

Tags: mysql

People,

Currently i have a string mysql field Class on a table.
It´s a code plus a description. I need to extract the description only (without a whitespace in the begining of the string).
The rule of formation of this field data follows:
N.N Description(without any digit or dots) or N.N. Description (without any digit or dots)
Where N is a number between 1 and 10.
I´ve tried this multiple replace but it remains two cases with one leading white space that i could not remove:
' Suspension'
and
' Reduction'

My multiplce replace is:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(class,'.',''),'1',''),'0',''),'2',''),'3',''),'4',''),'5',''),'6',''),'7',''),'8',''),'9',''))),'\r',''),'\t',''),'\n','')
```

What this leading white space could be so i can replace it? What could be missing?
Or anyone have a better idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are replacing with white space and this the modified string ends up with that. Why can't you use [`TRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function on your final replaced string to get rid of those leading spaces.